# Style -CSS a php session value

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

How to style php output?
Here is an code for example? 
I can only style with css the code who is in the echo.How to style the session value?

```
 echo "<h1>Logged in as:</h1>"  .$_SESSION['myusername'];
```

Any tip?

Comment: put `session value` also in a element for ex: span or div and write inline css

Comment: `echo "<h1>Logged in as:" .$_SESSION['myusername']. "</h1>";`

Comment: You must have an html element surrounding the session variable - and style that element. How exactly do you want to style it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `span` tag to format text inside `h1` tag :

```
echo "<h1 class='yourClass'>Logged in as:<span class='spanclass'>" .$_SESSION['myusername']. "</span></h1>"
```

CSS class (*for example*):

```
.spanclass{
   color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class to you html in php and add a style to your css file

**In css page**

```
.yourClass{

 //add your style

}
```

**In PHP**

```
 echo "<h1 class='yourClass'>Logged in as:</h1>"  .$_SESSION['myusername'];
```